# cocos2d pixel collision detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, sprite

i am currently writing a game with a number of rectangles (say 30), if a user clicks on one of the four sides a certain action will need to be taken. Trouble is each card will have the same side which will perform this action. For example with rectangle 1 the side which will perform this action will be the left, but rectangle 3 the side will be the top side. My guess is a pixel collision detection is needed here. What do you guys think? Also is there a good example on pixel collision using cocos2s out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use following code

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Rect1, Rect2)) 
{
     //Your code ...                
}
```

USING above **CGRectIntersectsRect** you can detect the collision pixels within a rectangular area.

Comment: I have that and that part works fine, however now i need to determine which side of the rectangle was intersected ie left, right bottom etc, what is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: take the two rectangle's center points, and see where they are relative to each other (ie x1 larger than x2? If so, rect1 is to the right of rect2).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Dhaval, here is the code i wrote a future reference for anyone who wishes to do similar, it can be further fine tuned, if i figure out a more accurate way of doing this i will update this thread accordingly

```
-(void)touchWhichSide:(CCSprite *)sprite1 collidingSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite2
{
    BOOL retValue = NO;

    CGPoint spriteCentre1 = sprite1.position;
    CGPoint spriteCentre2 = sprite2.position;

    NSLog(@"X %f",spriteCentre2.x - spriteCentre1.x);
    NSLog(@"Y %f",spriteCentre1.y - spriteCentre2.y);
    float xAxisDiff = spriteCentre1.x - spriteCentre2.x;
    float yAxisDiff = spriteCentre1.y - spriteCentre2.y;

    NSLog(@"x axis %f",xAxisDiff);
    NSLog(@"y axis %f",yAxisDiff);

    if((spriteCentre1.x < spriteCentre2.x) && (xAxisDiff < yAxisDiff))  
    {
        NSLog(@"right touch");
    }
    else if((spriteCentre2.x < spriteCentre1.x) && (xAxisDiff > yAxisDiff)) 
    {
        NSLog(@"left touch");
    }
    else if((spriteCentre2.y < spriteCentre1.y) && (yAxisDiff > xAxisDiff))
    {
        NSLog(@"Bottom touch");
    }
    else if((spriteCentre1.y < spriteCentre2.y) && (yAxisDiff < xAxisDiff))
    {
        NSLog(@"Top touch");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah yes... but what if the sprite is rotated!

Comment: yes good point, the solution was a little messy but it worked, this is what i did: I subclassed CCSprite and created a new attribute called state saving the current position if rotated  relative to that rotation. Depending on what side was touched i would use that information to determine which side of the rectangle was touched.

Answer (score 0):

yes good point, the solution was a little messy but it worked, this is what i did: I subclassed CCSprite and created a new attribute called state saving the current position if rotated relative to that rotation. Depending on what side was touched i would use that information to determine which side of the rectangle was touched. –

```
if((spriteCentre1.x < spriteCentre2.x) && (xAxisDiff < yAxisDiff))  
    {
    [HelloWorldLayer whichSideTouched:sprite1 sideTouched:kStateRightPlus touchingSprite:sprite2];
}
```

+(int)whichSideTouched:(SpriteCard  *)sprite sideTouched:(int)touched touchingSprite:(SpriteCard *)sprite2
{

switch (sprite.state) {
        case kStateUpPlus:
        case kStateUpMinus:
            if(touched == kStateDownPlus)
            {
                NSLog(@ "touched up ");
                [sprite setTop:sprite2];
                retValue = kStateUpPlus;
            }
            else if(touched == kStateRightPlus)
            {
                NSLog(@ "touch left");
                [sprite setRight:sprite2];
                retValue = kStateLeftPlus;
            }
}